# redirect dynamic url with .htaccess with removing some character dynamically

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two web sites

1. abc.com
2. pqr.com

I have redirected all the pages of pqr.com to abc.com.
If the page of pqr.com is pqr.com/xyz/ then it doesn't get the css after redirecting to abc.com, but if I remove the "/" it gets the css.

how should I remove "/" and redirect on pqr.com/xyz with .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right below the RewriteEngine On line, add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
```

to enforce a no-trailing-slash policy.